# Is there a way to output the current line being executed in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making software in python which shows how variables change within a given piece of code. I therefore want it to display at what line in the code the changes happen. How could I go about doing it?

Comment: You are making a debugger?

Comment: @BlackBear Not exactly, I'm making software that outputs Trace Tables for pieces of code

Comment: I would suspect you could write something like this using the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module. Or maybe using the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) of the source code.

Comment: [`python -m trace -t yourprogram`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) does this job. The linked documentation also covers the programmatic interface to that same functionality. If you have more specific needs not covered in those docs or the linked duplicate questions, please edit the question to be more specific as to what needs aren't already met.